# PowerApps User always sees prompt "is available for offline use" ( bis )

Tags: mobile, offline, banner

A banner with the message "App is available for offline use" is shown when I run the App. I don't know what happened last week but I'm pretty sure it's a problem that started to occur last week. I never get this message before with my app, but last week I was giving a try at my app and the message started to appear. ( to be clear I did not published any new version of my app nor installed a newer version of power app on my mobile ).

I've spent hours trying fix the problem but unsuccessfully. I think the message appears as the app initiate a network connexion. ( as a example : I just put a label on my homepage with Connection.Connected and the message appears as soon as the page is visible )